# Installed an extension on magento , giving an error

Tags: magento

I installed an extension on magento store. Name of the extension is **Mirasvit Advanced Product Feeds** 
The extension was in a zip file. After installing the extension, I started a validation test for the installed extension from the admin panel and i got this error.

Table 'feedexport/feed' not exists
Table 'feedexport/feed_history' not exists
Table 'feedexport/template' not exists
Table 'feedexport/custom_attribute' not exists
Table 'feedexport/performance_click' not exists
Table 'feedexport/performance_order' not exists
Table 'feedexport/performance_aggregated' not exists
Table 'feedexport/rule' not exists
Table 'feedexport/rule_product' not exists
Table 'feedexport/rule_feed' not exists
Table 'feedexport/feed_product' not exists
Table 'feedexport/mapping_category' not exists

Can anyone please help me with any possible solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in following way.

First disable all cache types if it is enabled. Then search for setup record for this Mirasvit extension in `core_resource` table. If a record is found then delete it. Re run you Magento store in browser (frontend or backend).